# Is it possible to group rows twice in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
someid    somestring
1         Hello
1         World
1         Blah
2         World
2         TestA
2         TestB
...
```

Currently I'm grouping by the id and concatenating the strings, so I end up with this:

```
1         Hello,World,Blah
2         World,TestA,TestB
...
```

Is it possible to do a second grouping so that if there are multiple entries that end up with the same string, I can group those too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just put your current query in an inner select and apply a new GROUP BY to the outer select. Note that you will probably want to use ORDER BY of GROUP_CONCAT to ensure that the strings are always concatenated in the same order.

```
SELECT somelist, COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT
        someid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(somestring ORDER BY somestring) AS somelist
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY someid
) AS T1
GROUP BY somelist
```

Result:

```
'Blah,Hello,World', 1
'TestA,TestB,World', 2
```

Here's the test data I used:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (someid INT NOT NULL, somestring NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (someid, somestring) VALUES
(1, 'Hello'),
(1, 'World'),
(1, 'Blah'),
(2, 'World'),
(2, 'TestA'),
(2, 'TestB'),
(3, 'World'),
(3, 'TestB'),
(3, 'TestA');
```

Comment: How efficient are sub-queries in general? There are always questions on here about "how can I make this one query/un-nest a query" etc, which implies that nested queries are bad in some way.

Comment: Correlated subqueries (where your inner query references the outer query) can be very slow if the optimizer doesn't figure out a way to execute it as a JOIN and instead executes the inner query once per row of the outer query. But this isn't a correlated subquery so there is no problem.

Comment: Just remember that GROUP_CONCAT() is length limited, generally to 1,024 bytes by default. This answer can break if the inner query has a "large" result set. You can get the current limit with `show variables like '%group_concat%'`